# Casting issue in aspnet core controller using repository that's implementing a generic interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The actual problem is here:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OrgController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<OrgRepository> _repository;
    public OrgController(IGenericRepository<OrgRepository> repo)
   {
        _repository = repo;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Org>> Get()
    {
        return await _repository.GetAllRecords();
    }
}
}
```

the GetAllRecords() line is telling me:

`Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<P5NCore.Repos itories.OrgRepository>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<P5NCore.Models.Org>>'(CS0029) (P5NCore)`

The GetallRecords() is repository code that actually returns the right type:

```
public class OrgRepository : IGenericRepository<Org>
    {
     private readonly OrgContext _context = null;
     public OrgRepository(IOptions<Settings> settings)
     {
         _context = new OrgContext(settings);
     }
     public async Task<IEnumerable<Org>> GetAllRecords(){
         try{
             return await _context.Orgs.Find(_=> true).ToListAsync();
         }
         catch (Exception ex){
             throw ex;
         }
     }
...
}
```

The Repo is implementing a generic interface:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T:class
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllRecords();
        Task<T> GetRecord(string id);
        Task AddRecord(T item);
    }
```

and I register the whole thing like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IGenericRepository<Org>, OrgRepository>();
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: You propably have classes with the same name `Org` in other namespaces. Repair this using for example `P5NCore.Repos itories.OrgRepository` in Controller and repo

Comment: Change `IGenericRepository<OrgRepository>` to `IGenericRepository<Org>` =)

Comment: @IlyaChumakov has it. It's your `private readonly` field

Comment: Thanks @IlyaChumakov, I spent a good hour trying to figure it out lol